# Redirect from one module to another

Tags: 8

I have form in one module.

```
  public static function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('test.route');
      $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
      $form_state->setRedirect('test.route');
  }
```

Trying to redirect the route of another module.

It's not redirecting from one module to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example

```
    use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

Its not working in Form validate.

Its working un submitform

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $url = Url::fromRoute('route.path');
        $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Already tried

Comment: It does not work in the form validation, but in the submit. I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it;s not working in Form Validate, but works in Submit